# Why is this loop seeming to change the value of a variable?

Tags: c++, types, double, rounding

The following code is meant to calculate 7 terms: tcapneg, tcappos, tneg1, tneg2, tpos1, tpos2, tzcap (only the calculation of tpos1 and tpos2 is shown here), and determine the entry that satisfies the condition of being the smallest positive non-zero entry.

```
int hitb;
double PCLx = 2.936728;
double PCLz = -0.016691;
double PDCx = 0.102796;
double PDCz = 0.994702;
double q = 0.002344;
double s = 0.0266;
double v = 0.0744;
double a = -q * PDCx * PDCx;
double b = s * PDCx - 2 * q*PCLx*PDCx - PDCz;
double c = -1.0*(PCLz + q * pow(PCLx, 2) - s * PCLx + v);
double d = b * b - 4 * a*c;

if (d >= 0.0f) // only take solution if t real
{
    tpos1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    tpos2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
}

printf("\n %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", tcapneg, tcappos, tneg1, tneg2, tpos1, tpos2, tzcap);
```

yielding the result:

```
 0.000000 0.000000 -40326.381162 -0.156221 -40105.748386 0.000194 0.016780
```

It is seen that the expected result should be smallest = tpos2 = 0.000194.

```
double smallest = -1.0;
double tlist[7] = { tcapneg, tcappos, tneg1, tneg2, tpos1, tpos2, tzcap };
const int size = sizeof(tlist) / sizeof(int);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (tlist[i] > EPSILON && (smallest == -1.0 || tlist[i] < smallest))
    {
        smallest = tlist[i];
    }
}
printf("\n %f", smallest);
```

The output for smallest = 0.000192, thus smallest != tpos2 != 0.00194. Why is there this small change in value for the selected smallest entry?

The result of smallest will be fed to the following code:

```
            if (smallest == tneg1 || smallest == tneg2)
            {
                hitb = 1;
            }
            else if (smallest == tpos1 || smallest == tpos2)
            {
                hitb = 2;
            }
            else if (smallest == tcappos)
            {
                hitb = 3;
            }
            else if (smallest == tcapneg)
            {
                hitb = 4;
            }
            else if (smallest == tzcap)
            {
                hitb = 5;
            }
```

In this case, we should satisfy the condition to write hitb = 2, however this is failing due to the inequality above.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please make it a habit to print *trailing* newlines. When `stdout` is connected to a terminal it will be *line buffered*, meaning that output is actually written when you write a newline. By using leading newlines, you output the *previous* line. In some situation that could lead to false impressions.

Comment: `double tlist[7] = { tcapneg, tcappos, tneg1, tneg2, tpos1, tpos2, tzcap };` -- `const int size = sizeof(tlist) / sizeof(int);` -- The array is of type `double`, not `int`.  This is the wrong usage of `sizeof`.  Might close this due to a typo.

Comment: The result of the bug that @PaulMcKenzie mentioned is you likely looped through 2 times as many items as your array contained. Usually (but not always) sizeof(int) is 4 and sizeof(double) is 8.

Comment: And to not have this bug occur, use `std::size(tList)`, and not the typo-prone usage of `sizeof` to figure out how big the array is.

Comment: Another way to solve your problem, since you have an actual array, is to use a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: Okay, thanks all. The problem seems to be solved after changing the line from
`const int size = sizeof(tlist) / sizeof(int);` to `const int size = std::size(tlist);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array `double tlist[7]` is in `double` with 7 elements. sizeof(double) is 8, so `sizeof(tlist)` is `8*7 = 56`. While `sizeof(int)` is 4, so your `size = sizeof(tlist) / sizeof(int)` is `56/4 = 14`. Your loop goes beyond number of elements in the array. It counts 7 more double values after the array in memory, because the array name is used as a `pointer`.

Here is my code to verify the above nanalysis

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double da[7] = {0.0, 0.0, -40326.381162, -0.156221, -40105.748386, 0.000194, 0.016780};
    const int sda = sizeof(da);
    const int sin = sizeof(int);
    const int siz = sda/sin;
    cout << "sda:" << sda << " sin:" << sin << " siz:" << siz << endl;

    for( int i=0; i<siz; i++ ) {
        cout << "da[" << i << "] = " << da[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output

```
sda:56 sin:4 siz:14
da[0] = 0
da[1] = 0
da[2] = -40326.4
da[3] = -0.156221
da[4] = -40105.7
da[5] = 0.000194
da[6] = 0.01678
da[7] = 2.07324e-317
da[8] = 8.48798e-314
da[9] = 1.9098e-313
da[10] = 0
da[11] = 1.31616e-312
da[12] = 0
da[13] = 6.95332e-310
```

The correct code is

```
size = sizeof(tlist) / sizeof(double);
```

Use the following option for GCC to report `runtime error` in this case

```
g++ -fsanitize=bounds -o main.e main.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you never iterate over the last elements of the array: you calculate the size as `sizeof(double*) / sizeof(int)` which is not true. Just use `std::vector` type for an array and iterate over it using iterator types:

```cpp
std::vector<double>tlist = ...
for(auto i = tlist.begin(); i != tlist.end(); i++)
{
    double v = (*i);
    /* ... */
}
```

Also you should thoroughly check the logic of your condition: is EPSILON positive?

Comment: Let's say the `sizeof(double*)` is 8. and the `sizeof(int)` is 4.  Both are reasonable.  Now 8 / 4 = 2.  There are not 2 elements in the OP's array.

Comment: No need to copy to a vector, you can use `std::begin(tlist)` and `std::end(tlist)`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the OPs code has `sizeof` applied to the array, not a pointer. So except for dividing by the wrong number, it's almost correct.